# Change MAC address in Yosemite

Tags: macos, mac, wifi, mac-address

To change the MAC address I use the common

```
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -z
sudo ifconfig en0 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
networksetup -detectnewhardware
```

It shows the changed MAC address when I run

```
ifconfig en0 |grep ether
```

Is this sufficient or should the changed address also appear in System Preferences -> Network and in the extended Wi-Fi details sub menu (<kbd>alt</kbd>+click on Wi-Fi symbol)? In both places the original MAC address is still shown although Terminal gives a different address.

Comment: Just an FYI... The fact is you cannot change the actual physical MAC Address of a NIC in that manner as it is encoded in it's EPROM. You can spoof a MAC Address in that manner however the actual physical MAC Address of a NIC will always be that of which it was programmed until reprogramed in the EPROM. While Wireshark will report the spoofed address that doesn't stop a hardware verification app that polling the actual physical hardware for its address from seeing the real address vs the spoofed address.

Answer (score 2):

This should be sufficient. After changing the MAC address this way you could use e.g. Wireshark to capture the network traffic. The new MAC address should be shown there. At least this works on my macbook.

Comment: Don't mind Wireshark. I checked my wi-fi router settings and found it registers all connected devices MAC addresses. It works. Once I changed it on my macbook, router showed new MAC address. Easy

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is this sufficient. But to make sure, run `networksetup -listallhardwareports` on your console.